# My counter in Python code is not working properly

Tags: python, counter

I am a novice programmer. I am writing a program. The essence of it is as follows: a random number is shown to the user. And he needs to answer "yes" if the number is even, or "no" if it is odd. The user must give the correct answer to three questions in a row. But my counter doesn't work and I don't understand why...

My code is:

```
from random import randint

score = 3

def is_even_game():

    print('Welcome!')
    print('May I have your name?')
    name = input()
    print(f'Hello, {name}!')
    
    rand_num = randint(1, 100)
    
    print(f'Question: {rand_num}')
    text = input()
    print('Your answer: ' + text)
    
    counter = 0
    while counter <= score:
        if rand_num % 2 == 0:
            answer = 'yes'
        else:
            answer = 'no'

        if text != answer:
            print(f'"{text}" is wrong answer. Correct answer was "{answer}"')
            print(f"Let's try again, {name}!")
            break
        print('Correct!')
        counter += 1
    else:
        print(f'Congratulations, {name}!')
    
is_even_game()
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please see [ask] -- you need to tell us what you expect your code to do, and what it actually does. Have you learned what `break` does? Why do you think it is applicable in this situation? Why do you think selecting _one_ random number, and asking the user for input _once_ is the correct approach? Why do you need a counter at all? What is the condition that needs to be satisfied to increment or reset this counter?

Comment: The creation of a random number is only done once, shouldn't this be inside the while loop so you ask about a new number each time you quiz the user?

Comment: try to make a flow chart diagram and see where it will be failed

Comment: You can include prints as an optional parameter for `input`: e.g. `name = input('May I have your name?')`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me :

```
from random import randint
score = 3

def is_even_game():

    print('Welcome!')
    print('May I have your name?')
    name = input()
    print(f'Hello, {name}!')

    counter = 0
    while counter < score: # Must be strictly inferior here, otherwise you
                           # could have written "while counter <= score + 1"
        rand_num = randint(1, 100)

        print(f'Question: {rand_num}')
        text = input()
        print('Your answer: ' + text)

        if rand_num % 2 == 0:
            answer = 'yes'
        else:
            answer = 'no'

        if text != answer:
            print(f'"{text}" is wrong answer. Correct answer was "{answer}"')
            print(f"Let's try again, {name}!")
            break # Stop the execution (if it's really what you want)
        else:
            counter = counter + 1 # "counter += 1" is also totally fine
            print('Correct!')
            print(f'Congratulations, {name}!')
            # If the counter is less than 3, loop again


is_even_game()
```

If you want to ask the question 3 times, you should reask it after each good answer, so put it in the loop, and change your `<=` to `<` in loops as you start counting from 0.

Also, you should pay attention to indentation (it matters even more in Python), and don't refrain from using the `print()` function to debug your program by printing the variables the values of which you need to know !

Answer (score 0):

I redesigned your code and it works now.

```
import random

print('Welcome!')
print('May I have your name?')
name = input()
print(f'Hello, {name}!')
score = 0
counter = 0
loop = 9

def game():
    rand_num = random.randint(1, 100)
    global counter
    print(f'Question No.{counter+1}: {rand_num}')
    text = input("Is this number even?")
    print('Your answer: ' + text)
    if counter < loop:
        if rand_num % 2 == 0:
            answer = 'yes'
        else:
            answer = 'no'

        if text != answer:
            print(f'"{text}" is wrong answer. Correct answer was "{answer}"')
            print(f"Let's try again, {name}!")
            counter += 1
            game()
        else:
            global score
            print('Correct!')
            score += 1
            counter += 1
            game()
    else:
        print(f"Congratulations, {name}!, you earned {score} points.")


game()
```

let me explain the "<" part too.
for <= the game will be repeated for 11th time because 10 = 10 counts after 10 times past (0<10[1st], 1<10[2nd], ... , 9<10[10th],10 = 10[11th]) but if you use < , game will be stopped at 10 <10 (which is False) as far as python already ran its 10th loop (0<10[1st], 1<10[2nd], ... , 9<10[10th]).

Answer (score 0):

`break` breaks the while loop, so you should use it only when you want it to end before the while condition is met. In your program, you do the opposite, you break the loop precisely when you want it to continue looping.

Here's a minimum example where I want the loop to be broken only when the answer is wrong (it's up to you to modify it for your particular task :) ).

```
name = input('May I have your name?')
print(f'Hello, {name}!')

questions = ["What's your name?", "What's your quest?", "What's your favourite color?"]
answers = [name, "To seek the Holy Grail", "Blue"]
score = 3
counter = 0

while counter < score:   
    answer = input(questions[counter])
    if answer != answers[counter]:
        break
    else:
        counter += 1

print(["Auuuuuuuugh!", "Right! Off you go"][counter == score])
```